# Push notification actions not showing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I currently have an iOS project but the push notification actions aren't showing. Here is the payload body I'm testing it with:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
  'alert' => $message,
  'sound' => 'default',
  'link_url' => $url,
  'category' => 'NEWS_CATEGORY',
  );
```

Here is the registerForPushNotifications in App Delegate:

```
 func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

    //allows notification actions by setting catagories
    let viewAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    viewAction.identifier = "VIEW_IDENTIFIER"
    viewAction.title = "View"
    viewAction.activationMode = .Foreground

    let newsCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    newsCategory.identifier = "NEWS_CATEGORY"
    newsCategory.setActions([viewAction], forContext: .Default)

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: [newsCategory])
  }
```

Any help on why the notification actions aren't showing is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you help me with this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076216/firebase-push-notification-action

Answer (score 1):

Seems to forgot add actually register setting to application. add

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

After  `let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: [newsCategory])`