# Firebase push notification action

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications

I just builded my first app with swift 3. Firebase is working good and I'm receiving notifications on my device. What I want to do is to set the action when user click the notification. I want to send to specific ProductViewController, with specific product ID (sent from backend). If user is logged in continue to ProductViewController, if not stay on login screen.

**AppDelegate.swift code:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let lagFreeField = UITextField()
    self.window?.addSubview(lagFreeField)
    lagFreeField.becomeFirstResponder()
    lagFreeField.resignFirstResponder()
    lagFreeField.removeFromSuperview()


    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self as? FIRMessagingDelegate

    } else {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge , .sound], categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]

    FIRApp.configure()

    print("AppDelegate")

   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    self.window?.rootViewController = tab
    if Defaults.hasKey(.logged), let logged = Defaults[.logged], logged == true{
        APIRequest.username = Defaults[.username]!
        APIRequest.password = Defaults[.password]!
        let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        self.window?.rootViewController = tab

    } else {
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("Userinfo \(userInfo)")
} ... other default functions
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire a segue with the identifier of the viewController you want to open ..

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ProductViewControllerSegue",sender: nil)
```

You also need to set segue through your storyBoard in order to achieve this..

Comment: I know this, but where can i ADD this line of code when i press the notification to execute this segue..?

Comment: You can send a notification Using notificationCenter to a function written in your main view controller that can execute this line ..